# QGIS - Topographic Position Index

Tags: qgis

I am trying to compute the TPI from a raster file (geotiff with elevation data) but when I run the tool it works forever. I have left the PC working over the weekend without any results. The file is 14mb... What can I possibly do wrong?

Comment: *Not enough rep to comment:* What are you using for your min and max radius? If you are using a large max radius the computation of TPI can become quite expensive and computing over the weekend without completion is possible. Would need more details though.